# Is it possible http request in one thread, response in another thread?

Tags: multithreading, http, curl

I have developed an application which curl an operators url for every sms and wait for the response. If application gets 200 Ok response, database is updated for that case. So, there is a delay for the response.

Is it possible that application will curl the http url in one thread and response will be received by another thread?

I have wrote my application in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

call to curl, wait for response and update DB are sequential operations. Executing  sequential operations in different threads cannot make things faster, but definitely makes them more complicated and error-prone.

Think instead how to run each sms/url job in a separate thread, or better say, on a thread pool, as the number of jobs can exceed reasonable number of threads.